# search archived messages using imap

Tags: imaplib

The following code will search for a string from emails found in "inbox".
My problem is that I need to search across all folders. M.selct("All") does not work.

```
import imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
M.login('sh.ak@gmail.com', 'xxx')
M.select("Inbox") 

ping=M.uid('search', None, '(HEADER Subject "Monthly Report")')
```

This is as good as typing this in google search bar:

> Subject: "Monthly Report" in:inbox

But I need the search without "in:inbox" If I type 
M.select("All")

I get the following error:

> error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED

How do I search across all mail including archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the "[Gmail]/All Mail" folder and search it.